# 404 error when trying to add item to cart on detail page

Tags: python, django, ajax, django-rest-framework

**edit**
I found the problem so when clicking "add" on the base website the absolute url is just base/updateItem but when i go on to detail page the url is /detail/3/updateItem

I'm making an online store. On the base URL (`127.0.0.1:8000`), I can add "recommended" products directly to the cart. But when I go into the page that has the details about this product (pictures, description, etc.) and try to add to cart from *there*, I get a 404 error at `127.0.0.1:8000/detail/1/updateItem`
.

**cart.js** (I suspect the error is in here):

```
var updateBtn = document.getElementsByClassName("update-cart")

for (i = 0; i < updateBtn.length; i++){
    updateBtn[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
        var productId = this.dataset.product
        var action    = this.dataset.action
        console.log(productId,action)
        console.log(user)
        if (user === "AnonymousUser"){
            console.log("user not logged in")
        }else{
           updateUserOrder(productId, action)
        }
    })
}
function updateUserOrder(productId, action){
    console.log("user created an order")

    var url = 'updateItem'

    fetch(url, {
        method:'POST',
        headers:{
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'X-CSRFToken':csrftoken,
        },
        body:JSON.stringify({'productId':productId, 'action':action})
    
    })
    .then((response) =>{
        return response.json()
    })
    .then((data) =>{
        location.reload()
    })
}
```

**urls.py**

```py
path('updateItem', views.updateItem, name='updateItem'),
path('cart', views.cartDetail, name='cart'),
```

**views.py**

```py
def cartDetail(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        customer = request.user.customer
        order, created = Order.objects.get_or_create(customer=customer, complete=False)
        items = order.orderitem_set.all()
    else:
        order = {'get_cart_total':0,} 
        items = []
    print(items)
    context ={
        'items':items,
        'orders':order,
    }

    return render(request,'cart.html',context)

def updateItem(request):
    data = json.loads(request.body)
    productId = data['productId']
    action = data['action']
    customer = request.user.customer
    product  = Product.objects.get(id=productId)
    order, created = Order.objects.get_or_create(customer=customer,complete=False)

    orderItem, created = OrderItem.objects.get_or_create(order=order, product=product)

    if action == "add":
        orderItem.quantity = (orderItem.quantity + 1)
    elif action == "remove":
        orderItem.quantity = (orderItem.quantity - 1)
    
    orderItem.save()

    if orderItem.quantity <= 0 or action=='delete':
        orderItem.delete()

    return JsonResponse("item was added", safe=False)
```

**models.py**:

```py
class Order(models.Model):
    customer        = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    date_oredred    = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    complete        = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=True, blank=True)
    transaction_id  = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)

    @property
    def get_cart_total(self):
        items = self.orderitem_set.all()
        total = sum([x.get_total for x in items])
        return total


    

class OrderItem(models.Model):
    product     = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    order       = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    quantity    = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True, blank=True)
    date_added  = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    @property
    def get_total(self):
        if self.product.pricePromo is None:
            total = self.product.priceNormal * self.quantity
        else:
            total = self.product.pricePromo * self.quantity
        
        return total
```

Let me know if I am missing any code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the `urls.py` add `/` at the end of `updateItem`

urls.py

```
path('updateItem/', views.updateItem, name='updateItem'),
```

and in your function updateUserOrder change the var url to /updateItem/

```
function updateUserOrder(productId, action){
    
    var url = '/updateItem/'
```

Answer (score 1):

in the cart.js I've changed url to absolute path and it works

Answer (score 0):

Absolute path means like below & this is the solution for 404 error..
var url = '/updateItem/'